# Outlook font family lost after downloading email pictures

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to create an email html template with font family "Gotham".

it is working fine but it reverts back to "New Times Roman" when I click download pictures button in the message which I see it very weird and I could not understand the reason or find a solution.

I'm using below code

```
<td style="font-family: 'Gotham' !important;">Test Font</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook (desktop), doesn't support web fonts.
Gotham isn't seen as an email safe font. Typically, these are:

- Arial
- Times New Roman
- Verdana
- Georgia

Reference - https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts/

To force Outlook to fall back to a similar and email safe font, I'd suggest adding this declaration in the head of your HTML:

```html
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,a,span,td,strong,li {
font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

This snippet targets Outlook specifically and will stop it from falling back to Times New Roman